# Efficient switching between windows in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I more easily switch between buffers in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394289/how-can-i-more-easily-switch-between-buffers-in-emacs)

While working with emacs I tend to keep many open windows. Unfortunately using `M-x other-window` is quite annoying. So far I have set up keyboard shortcut in my .emacs file: `(global-set-key (quote [backtab]) (quote other-window))`. That makes things a bit easier but I am looking for equivalents of commands `next-buffer` and `previus-buffer` that can be applied to windows.

Comment: I have M-x other-window on F11 and twice M-x other-window on F12. In 3-windowed setup that I use it works as 'next' and 'previous'.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: I usually have 8 windows. This may sound a bit odd but that`s my taste ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing window faster in Emacs (or repeating last shortcut with a single strike)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046597/changing-window-faster-in-emacs-or-repeating-last-shortcut-with-a-single-strike) and [Emacs, switch active window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91071/emacs-switch-active-window) and [How to switch between visible buffers in emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671819/how-to-switch-between-visible-buffers-in-emacs) and [Better window navigation in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858958/better-window-navigation-in-emacs)

Comment: The question was closed (correctly) but reason: Possible Duplicate:
[How can I more easily switch between buffers in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394289/how-can-i-more-easily-switch-between-buffers-in-emacs) is incorrect. Windows and buffers are two distinct things in emacs (windows are kind of viewports of buffers). Comment from @phils states better explanation of closing this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the following to your .emacs

```
(windmove-default-keybindings)
(setq windmove-wrap-around t)
```

Then you'll be able to switch between windows with `Shift+{left,up,down,right}` arrows. Shift modifier is a parameter to `windmove-default-keybindings`, so you can choose another one.

You may want to activate a `winner-mode`. It's a minor mode which remembers your window configurations and you can go to the previous/next configuration using `winner-undo` or `winner-redo`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. More information about the solution can be found on [emacs wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove)

Comment: _For any Spacemacs users:_ the suggested bit of code should be put inside the `dotspacemacs/user-init` function in your `.spacemacs` file.